# xcode 4 setting a lot of UIImageView's

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have 8 UIImageView in my view, all declared in the `.h` and `.m`.

I called them `img01`, `img02`, `img03`,..., `img08`

and I also have 8 pics, named `01.png`, `02.png`, `03.png`,..., `08.png`.

if I want to set the first `imageView` to the first pic I'll use the following command:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"];
    [img01 setImage:image];
```

What if I have a lot of *UIImageViews* and *pics*?

I tried to use this code but couldn't figure out how to do the last line of code.

```
int count = 1;
while (count <= 8) {

    NSString *countString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i", count];

    NSString *picname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%@.png", countString];

    NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img0%@", countString];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:picname];

    [img01 setImage:image];

    count++;

}
```

The code will only change the first imageView. I need it to change all the `imageViews`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `NSMutableArray`, and fill it with the UIImageViews. Currently you only set the first:

```
[img01 setImage:image];
```

You can do something like that:

```
NSMutbaleArray imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    NSString *countString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];
    NSString *picname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%@.png", countString];
    NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img0%@", countString];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:picname];
    UIImageView * view = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
    [view setImage:image];
    [imageViews addObject:view];
}
```

Comment: then what to do ? can you please explain it to me

Comment: @H.aLFaRSi - see edit, this is the idea. it is not tested as I don't have a Mac right now.

Comment: tried ur code and fixed a lot of the errors,, but still no images are loaded

Comment: Note that this code doesn't load the views, to do that you should loop over the array and add them as subviews.

Comment: At the code above, I created an array of UIImageViews, but I didn't add them to the display, to show you how to do it, I first need to see a little more of your code.